# How to make Level 1 sub-menu to overlap the Level 2 menu?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to achieve a effect in which `Level 2` menu appears beneath the `Level 1` menu. So far I've tried `z-index: 10;` and `z-index: 5;` for `.nav > ul > li > ul` and `.nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul` respectively. That ain't working for me. Is there any alternative to achieve the desired result?

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HgUAd/)

[image: How to make this Level 1 sub-menu to overlap the Level 2 menu?]

Markup:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Hover</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Hover Here</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>    
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav{
    background: #282828;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    position: relative;
}
.nav a{
    background: #282828;
    color: #ddd;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 24px;

}
.nav > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover, 
.nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover{
    background: #404040;
    color: #AFAFAF; 
}
.nav > ul > li > ul, .nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav > ul > li > ul > li, .nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.nav > ul > li > ul, .nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.nav > ul > li > ul {
    top: 75px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.nav > ul > li:hover > ul, .nav > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
.nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
    top: 100%;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
.nav > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul{
    left: 100%;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: what is the desired result you are looking for? I would say it works for me in chrome. which browser are you using?

Comment: @davidb: I took that screenshot on chrome only. I dont want that "Level 2" submenu to overlap "Level 1" submenu.

Comment: @SonuJoshi im sorry but my chrome browser is showing no overlap between level 2 and level 1

Comment: no overlap in Firefox 20.0.1 either

Comment: @deathApril http://i.imgur.com/41bcE2T.png

Comment: oh,, if by "overlap" you mean "something is in front of something else during the transition period, when it should be behind it - nevermind that in the final state the elements are disjoint" then it makes sense ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Edit :

Got it!! Add `z-index: -1;` to last `ul` :)

```
.nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul{
     z-index: -1;
}
```

See [W3's doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-z-index) about CSS 2.1 z-index and negative values :

> [...] Boxes may have negative stack levels [...]
>
> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in
>   back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking
>      context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most
>      negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including
>      inline tables and inline blocks.
> 6. the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned
>      descendants with stack level 0.
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least
>      positive first).

[Updated & working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RtFzh/3/)

---

Previous answer :

<strike>Add `z-index: n;` where n > 0 to your last `ul`, and make the slide go to 70% of the left.</strike>

```
.nav > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul{
    left: 70%;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
.nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    z-index: 1;                 /* Its position is already set to absolute, line 42 */
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RtFzh/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, though I think you should add it to your answer - +1

Comment: It's still overlapping. 
http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/1236/8d27c4f53fec4899a1b7c6a.png

Comment: @SonuJoshi I think I misunderstood you. I'll edit my question

Comment: @SonuJoshi [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RtFzh/1/) - It's really weird... Everything is going fine BUT the `a` tag, which `z-index` is set to `auto`, even if I force the value. Any clue?

Comment: @Bigood: That's exactly where I'm stuck. I tried every possible thing but nothing helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

Add a position: relative; and z-index: 100 to "Hover here" link and z-index: 1; to a Level2 submenu

```
.nav a {
    background: #282828;
    color: #ddd;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

.nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/YLPLx/1/